# Controller GetMapping/RequestMapping not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm practicing my springboot knowledge so I'm trying to create a simple Todo Application. When I run my main app at localhost:8080/tasks/list, I'm getting a Whitelabel error page even If I configure the correct routing for my html file. I'm using JSP at this time, I also created a thymeleaf version of this but still I'm getting the same error. Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5BR8.png)

MainApp.java

```
package task.springboot.todo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TodoappOracleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TodoappOracleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

TaskController.java

```
package task.springboot.todo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;




@Controller
@RequestMapping("/tasks")
public class TaskController {

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String showTodoList() {
        
        
        return "todo-list";
    }
    
}
```

todo-list.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Todo Application </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Welcome to Todo Application</h2>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>task.springboot.todo</groupId>
    <artifactId>todoapp_oracle</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>todoapp_oracle</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
#
#
#
#
# Oracle Database Datasource
#
#
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=password

#
#
#
#
```

Comment: You didn't add the thymeleaf dependency to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Please add thymeleaf dependency to the `pom.xml`

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

and change the file extension from `.jsp` to `.html` `(todo-list.html)` and place it under  path `src/main/resources/templates`

Comment: In this project, I'm not using thymeleaf but JSP, I'd just stated from my question above that even in my thymeleaf version of this, the controller didn't work. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Can you share the pom.xml with thymeleaf?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Change file extension from .jsp to .html